Securing Assets in Flutter Windows Apps: How to Hide or Encrypt Assets Folder?"
I'm developing a Flutter application for Windows, and I'm concerned about the security of the assets included in the application bundle. In the release version of the app, I want to ensure that the assets folder, containing sensitive resources such as images and configuration files, is either hidden or encrypted to prevent unauthorized access.
i don't know what to do but i guess i need a way to encrypt all assets in a way that only the app can access on runtime .
but how to exclude assets folder from building the release version phase
